# How to take a json object and output a UL/LI on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

using rails, if there are errors, I get back something like so:

```
{"email":["has already been taken"]}
```

How can I take that JSON and create a UL on the page of the errors

```
<div id="errors">
    <ul>
       <li><b>Email</b> has already been taken</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

**Update**

If I alert the error object provided by rails I get:

```
{&quot;email&quot;:[&quot;can't be blank&quot;]}
```

Thanks

Comment: next time insted of "alert"ing it, use a browser with a debug console/inspector (Chrome, Firefox+Firebug, IE9+<F12>) and use the command `console.log(error)` (assuming error is the name of the object)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have an array as the value of "email", the data format looks odd to me. BUT using your JSON *verbatim*, here's what you can do (I assume you'll have multiple error values):

```
var myJSON = {"email":["has already been taken"], "password":["has already been taken"]};

var html = '<ul>';
for (var key in myJSON)
{
   html += '<li><b>' + key + '</b> ' + myJSON[key][0] + '</li>'
}

html += '</ul>';

document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = html;
```

To capitalize "Email", you just need to define CSS style like so:

```
#errors li b
{
   text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

PS: This could be much cleaner/easier if you use a JS framework.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you have should work. You have it all, you just did not show your .js partials which I'm sure you have:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.js
    else
      @errors = @user.errors
      format.js { render 'errors.js'}
    end
  end
end
```

I'm assuming you are using jQuery.

`app/viiews/users/update.js`

This one you just need a flash notice or something.

`app/viiews/users/errors.js`

```
jQuery("#errors").html("<div><%= escape_javascript(render(@errors)) %></div>");
```

make sure you repalce jQuery with $ if that is what you are using.

You need to have this in your devise edit area app/views/devies/registrations/edit:

```
<ul id="errors">
  <%= render @errors if @errors %>
</ul>
```

Then you can redefine you errors partial:

app/views/users/_errors.js

```
<li>
  <%= error.name %> or whatever value.
</li>
```

Comment: All done, I edited it a bunch so glance over it again. Let me know if there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) could be used for this (I noticed the question was tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)):

```
var messages, errorMarkup = '';
for (var error in errors) {
    messages = errors[error];
    errorMarkup += "<ul>" + $.map(messages, function(el) {
        return "<li><b>" + error +"</b> " + el + "</li>";
    }).join('') + "</ul>";
}

$("#errors").append(errorMarkup);
```

(If you really wanted to get crazy you could reduce this even further)

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ymPsu/

---

**Edit:** Here's the crazy version, using only `$.map`:

```
var errorMarkup = $.map(errors, function(errorList, key) {
    return "<ul>" + $.map(errorList, function(message) {
        return "<li><b>" + key + "</b> " + message + "</li>";
    }).join('') + "</ul>";
}).join('');

$("#errors").append(errorMarkup);
```